# plugin:postcss-lit Unexpected token (1:0) after appending an element to the head

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, vaadin

I have a javascript class where i want to append a new element to the head which conclude a css file:

```
var link = document.createElement("link")
link.rel = "stylesheet"
link.href = "./scripts/styles.css"
document.head.appendChild(link)
```

My css file looks like this:

```
.custom-class {
    background-color: black;
}
```

I have npm installed and also the postcss package up to date.

If i'm going to start my Program (its a Vaadin Program that uses ShepherdJS) and going to execute the Tour, i get the following error Message:

```
[plugin:postcss-lit] Unexpected token (1:0)
1  |  .custom-shepherd-class {
   |  ^
2  |      background-color: black;
3  |  }
```

When i start the Tour through a Vaadin Button, there appers an Error Window containing the Error above. If i click somewhere else out of the Error Window it disappears and when im going to switch back to the developer tools in the browser, there is a new file styles.css inside the DOM but without any code in it.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Where is the CSS file located?

Comment: in the same folder like the script

Comment: Which folder in the project is that? There is a difference between the `frontend` folder in the root (used by Vite while bundling) and static resources you can load on demand later, which can be placed in e.g. `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` in a Java project

Comment: I face the same problem, not sure what causes this.